# D3 update pattern not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a very simple example to understand the d3 update pattern to dynamically update a list, as the underlying data changes. But the list keeps getting bigger and bigger without updating as expected. My expected output looks something like:

- 1: 23.4564
- 2: 45.7621
- 3: 71.5487

This keeps updating the values instead of adding new bullet points like shown in the image attached.

---

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="options">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1" value="1">
        <label for="1">One</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" value="2">
        <label for="1">Two</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3" value="3">
        <label for="1">Three</label>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selection = d3.select("ul").selectAll("li");
    var data=[];
    window.setInterval(loadData,5000);
    function loadData() {
        data = [{id: 1, value: Math.random()*100},
            {id: 2, value: Math.random()*100},
            {id: 3, value: Math.random()*100}
        ]
        update(data);
    }

    function update(data) {
        var join = selection.data(data, (d) => d.id)
        join.enter().append("li").text((d)=>{return d.id+": "+d.value;})
        join.text((d)=>{return d.id+": "+d.value;})
        join.exit().remove()
        
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give us a working, runnable [mre], using dummy data. With minimal, we also mean stripping out the unrelated stuff, like your python logic. Just use a javascript object with `Math.random()` to generate some data

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have edited the question to run here itself, according to your suggestion.

Comment: Since you're using d3 V6, I recommend using `.join` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this behavior is you don't update your original selection:

```
 var selection = d3.select("ul").selectAll("li");
```

This is an empty selection, as selections are immutable, it remains an empty selection after you enter things in the update function. Consequently, you'll only ever enter things as there's nothing to update in this empty selection. Simply make this selection in the update function - this way the selection won't be empty if list items have already been appeneded.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="options">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1" value="1">
        <label for="1">One</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2" value="2">
        <label for="1">Two</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="3" value="3">
        <label for="1">Three</label>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    var data=[];
    window.setInterval(loadData,5000);
    function loadData() {
        data = [{id: 1, value: Math.random()*100},
            {id: 2, value: Math.random()*100},
            {id: 3, value: Math.random()*100}
        ]
        update(data);
    }

    function update(data) {
        var selection = d3.select("ul").selectAll("li");
        var join = selection.data(data, (d) => d.id)
        join.enter().append("li").text((d)=>{return d.id+": "+d.value;})
        join.text((d)=>{return d.id+": "+d.value;})
        join.exit().remove()
        
    }
</script>
</html>
```